# How to put only one table td into an array

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a table like this:

```js
var markup = "<tr> " +
        "<td><center>" + count + "</center></td>"+
        "<td><center><input type='checkbox' name='record'></center></td>"+
        "<td>" + id_dept + "<input type='hidden' name='team"+count+"' value='" + team + "'></td>" +
        "<td style='border-right:0px;border-left:0'>" + name + "</td>"+
        "<td style='border-right:0px;border-left:0'><input  name='empid"+count+"' value='" + empid + "'></td>" +
        "<td style='border-right:0px;border-left:0'><input type='hidden' name='name"+count+"' value='" + name + "'></td>" +
        "<td style='border-right:0px;border-left:0'><input type='hidden' name='bgian"+count+"' value='" + bgian + "'></td>" +
    "</tr>";

$("table[id=table-pss] tbody").append(markup);
```

I want to put the td "empid" into an array.
Here's what I've done so far:

```js
    var myTableArray = [];
    $("table[id=table-pss] tbody tr").each(function() {
        var arrayOfThisRow = [];
        var tableData = $(this).find('td');
        if (tableData.length > 0) {
            tableData.each(function() { 
                arrayOfThisRow.push($(this).text()); 
            });
           myTableArray.push(arrayOfThisRow);
        }
    });
    console.log(myTableArray);
```

It adds the whole td's to array though, I'm wondering how to add only a td to array.
thank you

Comment: You need the whole td or the empID value only ?

Comment: I need the all values from empID td

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need assign an `id` to your `empID` `input` to be able to find it from the table.

For that you can use `.find()` function and to get the input `value` just use `.val()` function.

**Live Demo:**

```js
var myTableArray = [];
$("table[id=table-pss] tr").each(function() {
  var tableData = $(this).find('td');
  var empID = tableData.find('#empID').val()
  if (tableData.length > 0) {
    myTableArray.push(empID);
  }
});

console.log(myTableArray); //["10"] empID
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table style="width:100%" id="table-pss">
  <tr>
    <th>Firstname</th>
    <th>Lastname</th>
    <th>EmpID</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td style='border-right:0px;border-left:0'>Bob</td>
    <td style='border-right:0px;border-left:0'>Something</td>
    <td style='border-right:0px;border-left:0'><input id="empID" name='empid"+count+"' value='10'></td>
    <td style='border-right:0px;border-left:0'><input type='hidden' name='name"+count+"' value='" + name + "'></td>

  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: @Syns You are welcome - Happy to help always. Happy coding :)